# MySQL group by empty and non-empty values

Tags: mysql, group-by

At present, I have something like:

```
select sum(total) from table_name where field != ''
UNION
select sum(total) from table_name where field = ''
```

It works but I'm curious if it is possible to use "group by" to filter by empty and non-empty values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN field != '' THEN total ELSE 0) NONEMPTY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = '' THEN total ELSE 0) EMPTY from table_name
```

Try above query.

Here i had used `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: I cannot see GROUP BY here

Comment: Well, the question is very specific

Comment: Yes, you're not answering the question